# svelte-kit / scss how to make the footer go the the bottom of the page

Tags: css, sass, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-preprocess

I'm new in svelte-kit

as a learning project, I want to check how to style the page

I use `__layout. svelte` with flex property in CSS(scss) to fill the page with the main content and make the header on top and the footer on the bottom.
I used the following code:

```js
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<main>
    <slot />
</main>

<footer>Footer</footer>

<style lang="scss">
    :global {
    
        body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;

            #svelte {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
    header {
        background: #333;
        color: rgb(100, 230, 170);
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;

    }
  main {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

    footer {
        background: #ddd;
        color: #333;
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        justify-content: center;
    }
</style>
```

but I'm getting the main body stretched and the footer is not at the bottom.

as in the below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding  `id ="svelte"` in the dev of the `src\app.html`

this will make the `#svelte`  find the id and make the component display property flex

the `src\app.html` should be:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%svelte.assets%/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        %svelte.head%
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="svelte">%svelte.body%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution for SvelteKit's initial project

---

**1. Append this to your `app.pcss`**

```
html {
  display: flex;              /* Make  <html> of type flex */
  min-height: 100%;           /* Force <html> to fill the whole page */ 
} body {
  flex-grow: 1;               /* Force <body> to fill the whole page */
  display: flex;              /* Make  <body> of type flex */
} #svelte-init {
  flex-grow: 1;               /* Force <div>  to fill the whole page */
  display: flex;              /* Make  <div>  of type flex */
  flex-direction: column;     /* Force <div>  to be vertical */
}
```

---

**2. Edit your `app.html`**

Remove `style` tag, and add `id="svelte-init"` to the main `<div>`

```
<div id="svelte-init">%sveltekit.body%</div>
```

**Tip:** These two steps will ensure that all the root elements are filling the whole page.

---

**3. Usage**

Now, to automatically stretch any component; simply add `flex-grow: 1;` to the component's style, or just `grow` if you are using **Tailwind CSS**.

```
<div class='grow'>  <h1>Content<h1/>  <div/>
```

[image]

**Tip:** In this example, the `grow` is applied to the central component `<div>`, so that the `footer` will always stay at the bottom, no matter the resolution or content dimensions inside the central `<div>`.